# Sin and Cosine Calculating Phase Shift

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I am revisiting Sin and Cos as an adult now and want to better understand why we set the function of sin to zero when calculating the phase shift. For instance in the equation $y = a\sin(bx+c)$, to find the phase shift why do we set $bx+c = 0$ to find what $c$ is? What is $b$ doing to the graph exactly?

Comment: What are thinking is the effect of b on the graph?

Comment: Hint:- Sine wave repeats itself after certain time period